# How to install VLC version 1.1.9?

Tags: installation, vlc, versions

I want to install older version of VLC (1.1.9) because of the sound bug in 2.* which makes it unusable (sound is distorted when the user sets the volume > 100% and then you can't fix it anymore). I've googled about the bug and found out that it's being fixed, but I don't want to install 2.0.4, because it's still a nightly build. The 2.0.3 version (in repos) has this bug.

I tried with Synaptic -> removed vlc 2.0.3 -> right_clicked vlc package -> Properties -> Versions, but there are no older versions. I've found [official source (.tar.gz)](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/1.1.9/) but I don't want to compile it myself. I [can't find](https://www.google.si/search?oq=vlc%201.1.9%20filetype%3adeb&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vlc%201.1.9%20filetype%3adeb#hl=sl&sclient=psy-ab&q=vlc%201.1.9%20filetype%3adeb&oq=vlc%201.1.9%20filetype%3adeb&gs_l=serp.3...417231.424867.2.425066.18.17.1.0.0.4.205.2358.0j16j1.17.0...0.0...1c.1.I_39VQy4n9k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=4ba7bc7cd025fb2f&bpcl=35466521&biw=1280&bih=626) any .deb files.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the VLC 1.1.9 deb here:

- 32 bit - http://launchpadlibrarian.net/69370596/vlc_1.1.9-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
- 64 bit - http://launchpadlibrarian.net/69370658/vlc_1.1.9-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

You should consider locking the `vlc` package to prevent it from getting updated accidentally again.

- [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: Problems - now old dependencies are not satisfied :) Tried installing (first) vlc-nox from the same website and then there are other dependencies not satisfied. I'm afraid to go further so I won't be doing this recursively. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

- [Download here](http://www.oldapps.com/linux/vlc_player.php?old_vlc_player=3)
- Extract the downloaded `.tat.bz2` package
- To install please read `INSTALL` file which guide you how to install it.

> **Configuring**
>
> A typical way to configure VLC is:
>
> `./configure --prefix=/usr`
>
> See `./configure --help` for more information.
>
> **Building VLC**
>
> Once configured, run 
>   `make` to build VLC.
>
> **Installing and running VLC**
>
> You can install the VLC and its plugins by typing:
>
> ```
> make install
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I am sure many will find it useful. But for the simplicity's sake I'll download .deb from @Edgar's answer.

Comment: @PrimožKralj I understand :)

Comment: If you see my third comment from selected answer (@Edgar) - I am having dependency issues now. Will installing it this way (building from source) help or will I have the same problem, if you know?

Comment: @PrimožKralj You don't have to even install `VLC` after building using that `.tat.bz2`. If you read it the `READ` file. You can run it from `.vlc` directory. Anyway, i didn't tried installing that package. So, i can't tell you that it doesn't have dependency issue. You should try it :)